# How To in CakePHP 3: Upload multiple images to server and save each image in database using cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, image, cakephp, file-upload

I am working on multiple image file uploads using cakephp 3, where, I want those images be uploaded in server as specified in directory path of my code and, each of the uploaded image should be save in database (am using MySQL Database).

On my current build, I can select multiple images in my form, fortunately, after submitting my form, all images are successfully uploaded to server image directory path as I expected, the thing is only one(1) image are saved in database, as it should saved all and each of the images in database.

Herewith a copy of code in my ImageUploadController:

```
public function add()
{
    $UploadedImage = array();
    $uploadedImage = $this->UploadedImages->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $images = array();

        $images = $this->request->data['name'];

        foreach ($images as $key => $image) {

          if(!empty($image[$key].$image['name'])){
            $fileName = $image[$key].$image['name'];
            $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT.'img/press-releases/';
            $uploadFile = $uploadPath.$fileName;


            if(move_uploaded_file($image[$key].$image['tmp_name'],$uploadFile)){

                $uploadedImage->name = $fileName;
                $uploadedImage->image_dir = 'press-releases/';
                $uploadedImage->status = $this->request->data['status'];

                $this->UploadedImages->save($uploadedImage);

            } else {  $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to upload image, please try again.'));  }


           } else { $this->Flash->error(__('Please choose an image to upload.')); } 

        }//EOF FOREACH      

    }

    $this->set(compact('uploadedImage'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['uploadedImage']);
}
```

And here is my simple form: add.ctp file:
[simple multiple image upload form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3jON.png)

And here is my model table UploadImageTable:

```
class UploadedImagesTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('uploaded_images');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('name');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('image_dir');

        $validator
            ->boolean('status')
            ->allowEmpty('status');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

I am quite new CakePHP 3, so you all guys who knew something about this uploading multiple images and saving each images in a database, please give me a hand or something could help me out of this, coz' am kinda stucked in this thing. Any help from you will be much appreciated.

For more additional details, herewith added a screenshot of my debugger SQL Logs.[In the image,I tried to upload 5 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji69g.png)

if you can see the image, as I tried to upload 5 images; at first query it executes an INSERT to my table and then the next other queries are UPDATE, which should be INSERT. I am wondering why DML(Data Manipulation Language)suddenly change in such queries.

more thanks in advance,
Mary

Comment: thank you for that edit proposal.. appreciate it.

Comment: You could use my plugin or just look at it. It's exactly doing what you're trying but on a higher level of abstraction to provide file storage for everything in your application, not just images. https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage Read the documentation and feel free to ask qustions on IRC or the Slack channel. I must admit it's probably not *that* newbie friendly because it uses the CakePHP event system and might overall not that easy to understand if you're not familiar with SoC, DRY and design patterns.

Comment: Hello burzum, I just read and tried to work around for a while your FileStorage plugin and its really amazing, but honestly, I think it would really take me sometime to understand the whole thing how it works, like your SoC's thing , am kinda new in cakephp and still trying to explore its core.But all I can say for sure that I will use yours in some other time. I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to save several Images you have to create also multiple Entities to save in your database. With your current Controller you're creating a single Entity and saving the data to this Entity.

In your UploadedImagesController try the following:

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->getData();

        $images = $data['name'];
        $path = 'img/press-releases/';

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            if(!empty($image['name'])) {
                $fileName = $image['name'];
                $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . $path;
                $uploadFile = $uploadPath . $fileName;

                if(move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) {
                    // Create a new Entity over here for each uploaded image
                    $uploadedImage = $this->UploadedImages->newEntity();
                    $uploadedImage->name = $fileName;
                    $uploadedImage->image_dir = $path;
                    $uploadedImage->status = $data['status'];

                    $this->UploadedImages->save($uploadedImage)
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to upload image, please try again.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Please choose an image to upload.'));
            }
        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('uploadedImage'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['uploadedImage']);
}
```

You can solve this problem also by [saving multiple Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities) directly. You may also want to outsource your code to a Model or a [Behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html) to make it reusable in other Controllers. Like burzum mentioned it could be wise to use a [file storage plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#files) to add things like file hashing and/or unique Ids (eg. UUID). Otherwise you could upload files with the same name...

Comment: All I can say is "Wow" and "Thank you" your code works like a charm honey, I am so very happy. I just copy the code and replace the whole ADD function in mine and added some semicolon after (I guess you just forgot) "$this->UploadedImages->save($uploadedImage)" and it works. Thank you so much.